# Set lower bound and upper bound to get table rows

Tags: table, rpc, get-table, c#

I am using eos-sharp to get table rows in ASP.NET.
By default in the table, I want to show the latest 10 records of the table. So I get them using:

```
GetTableRowsResponse tabledata = await eos.GetTableRows(new GetTableRowsRequest()
{
  json = true,
  code = contract,
  scope = contract,
  table = tables[0],
  reverse = true,
  lower_bound="0",
  upper_bound="-9",
  limit = 10
});
```

Now I need the next and previous 10 records. I tried for the next 10 records:

```
lower_bound="10",
upper_bound="-19",
```

But not getting records as expected.
What values for lower bound and upper bound should be set? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lower_bound and upper_bound set the range of primary key of items you want to retrieve. If you want to get first 10 items, then call get_table_rows by lower_bound and upper_bound with the value `""`, and it will return "next_key" in the result. Then pass the value of "next_key" to lower_bound (or if you want to call with `"reverse": true`, then next_key needs to be passed to upper_bound). You don't need to set both of lower_bound and upper_bound, because the number of items is deteremined by `"limit": 10`.

#### Updated(04/17/2021)

EosSharp is outdated. You need to add EosSharp to your project (instead of installing by NuGet), and modify it.

https://github.com/GetScatter/eos-sharp/blob/32bca887/EosSharp/EosSharp.Core/Api/v1/Definitions/EosApiMethodDef.t4#L252-L261

```
            Response = new Field[] 
            {
                new Field() { Name = "rows", Type = "List<object>"},
                new Field() { Name = "more", Type = "bool" },
                new Field() { Name = "next_key", Type = "string" } // add this line
            },
            GenericResponse = new Field[] 
            {
                new Field() { Name = "rows", Type = "List<TRowType>"},
                new Field() { Name = "more", Type = "bool" },
                new Field() { Name = "next_key", Type = "string" } // add this line
            }
```

Comment: If I set  lower_bound and upper_bound with the value `""`, it returns the first 10 records, whereas I need the latest or last 10 records. So, I can get them by `lower_bound="0"` and
  `upper_bound="-9"`. This is solved for the primary keys of type `integer`. Can you help more with the key type `name`? How to get the latest records and set the lower_bound for the next 10 records?

Comment: ```next_key``` is not returned by `GetTableRows` in  API.

Comment: @Varsh upper_bound is the upper boundary value of primary key, not item's index. As you know primary key is uint64_t, so '-9' doesn't make sense here. With `reverse = True`, you can get last 10 items without lower_bound and upper_bound.